# not able to display material-ui dropdown with props values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to incorporate material-ui DropDown element into my page but I am getting map errors

My page code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Button, Dropdown, Form} from 'semantic-ui-react'
import SimpleReactValidator from 'simple-react-validator';
import cookie from 'react-cookies'
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'

const jsonData = require('../../../../../jsonData/data.json');
const dummyData = require('../../../../../jsonData/dummy.json');
import auth, {
    axiosInst as axios,
    removeElement,
    addElement,
    beforeSubmiteShaker,
    afterSubmiteShaker
} from "../../../../helper";
import QuestionsFilters from '../../../../components/QuestionsFilters'
import DropDown from '../../../../components/ui/Select/Select'

const items = [
    {value: 1, primaryText: 'Dhaval'},
    {value: 2, primaryText: 'Dhavalu'},
    {value: 3, primaryText: 'Dhavalaa'},
]

class RegisterCandidate extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            firstname: "",
            lastname: "",
            mobile_no: "",
            email: "",
            password: "",
            city_id: "",
            preference_list: [],
            medium: "", //how did u find us
            is_looking_for: "",
            affiliate: "",
            revert: "",
            emailExist: "",
            mobileExist: "",
            isLogin: false,
            historyRoute: "",
        };
        this.validator = new SimpleReactValidator();

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchCities()
        this.props.fetchPreferences()
    }

    change(e) {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    };

    dropDownChange(e, {value, name}) {
        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        })
    }

    emailcheck(e) {
        if (this.validator.fieldValid('email')) {
            let uri = '/email/exists';
            axios.get(uri, {
                params: {email: this.state.email}
            })
                .then((response) => {
                    this.setState({emailExist: response.data});
                    if (response.data.status != 'Failed') {
                        removeElement("p[id='serv-error email-exist']")
                        return axios.get('/droppedregistrations/add', {
                            params: {email: this.state.email}
                        }).then((response) => {
                            console.log("Email Dropped " + response.data)
                        }).catch((error) => {
                            console.log('failed')
                        })
                    } else {
                        removeElement("p[id='serv-error email-exist']")
                        addElement("#email", "serv-error email-exist", "This email already exists.")
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('error Email')
                })
        }
    }

    mobilecheck(e) {
        if (this.state.mobile_no != isNaN && this.state.mobile_no.length == 10) {
            let uri = '/number/exists';
            axios.get(uri, {
                params: {mobile_no: this.state.mobile_no}
            }).then((response) => {
                this.setState({mobile_noExist: response.data});
                if (response.data.status != 'Failed') {
                    removeElement("p[id='serv-error mobile-exist']")
                    return axios.get('/droppedregistrations/add', {
                        params: {mobile_no: this.state.mobile_no}
                    }).then((response) => {
                        console.log("mobile dropped " + response.data)
                    }).catch((error) => {
                        console.log('failed')
                    })
                } else {
                    removeElement("p[id='serv-error mobile-exist']")
                    addElement("#mobile_no", "serv-error mobile-exist", "This mobile already exists.")
                }
            })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('You are experiencing slow internet please be patient and try again later')
                })
        }
    }

    addUserSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        beforeSubmiteShaker("s_reg_submit", "shaker")


        if (this.validator.allValid()) {
            const userDetails = {//add data to a donstant to pot
                firstname: this.state.firstname,
                lastname: this.state.lastname,
                email: this.state.email,
                password: this.state.password,
                mobile_no: this.state.mobile_no,
                city_id: this.state.city_id,
                medium: this.state.medium,
                is_looking_for: this.state.is_looking_for,
                preference_list: this.state.preference_list,
                affiliate: this.state.affiliate

            }

            let uri = '/register/candidate';
            axios.post(uri, userDetails)
                .then((response) => {
                    this.setState({revert: response.data});
                    const gotBack = this.state.revert
                    if (gotBack.status === 'Success') {
                        cookie.remove('token')
                        cookie.save('token', gotBack.token, {path: '/'})
                        if (cookie.load('token')) {
                            this.setState({isLogin: true})
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log('Something went wrong while redirect.')
                        }
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    if (error.response.status === 422) {
                        afterSubmiteShaker("s_reg_submit", "shaker")
                        $.each(error.response.data.errors, function (index, value) {
                            var errorDiv = '#' + index;
                            $(errorDiv).after("<p id='serv-error' class='validation-message'>" + value + "</p>");
                        });
                    }
                })
        } else {
            this.validator.showMessages();
            this.forceUpdate();
            afterSubmiteShaker("s_reg_submit", "shaker")
        }
    }

    render() {

        const {
            firstname,
            lastname,
            mobile_no,
            email,
            password,
            city_id,
            preference_list,
            medium,
            is_looking_for,
            affiliate,
            isLogin
        } = this.state;

        //to get the items in level of education
        let looking_for = jsonData.looking_for;
        var looking_fors = []

        for (let i = 0; i < looking_for.length; i++) {
            looking_fors.push(looking_for[i]['value']);
        }

        if (isLogin) {
            return <Redirect to='/register/candidate/step2'/>;
        } else {

            return (
                <section className="container mt-3">
                    {/*one click register section*/}
                    <div className="row p-3">
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <div className="card text-center">
                                <div className="card-body">
                                    <h3>Register Using</h3>
                                    <br/>
                                    <a href="/" className={"btn btn-block btn-lg btn-info"}> Register with Facebook</a>
                                    <a href="/google/redirect" className={"btn btn-block btn-lg btn-danger"}> Register
                                        with Google</a>
                                    <br/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {/*end of one click register section*/}

                        {/*manuel register section*/}
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <div id="shaker" className="card">
                                <div className="card-body">
                                    <h5 className="card-title">Register Candidate</h5>
                                    <Form onSubmit={this.addUserSubmit.bind(this)}>
                                        <Form.Field>
                                            <label>First Name*</label>
                                            <input name="firstname" id="firstname" value={firstname}
                                                   onChange={e => this.change(e)} type="text"
                                                   placeholder='Enter First Name*'/>
                                            {this.validator.message('first name', firstname, 'required|alpha')}
                                        </Form.Field>
                                        <Form.Field>
                                            <label>Last Name*</label>
                                            <input name="lastname" id="lastname" value={lastname}
                                                   onChange={e => this.change(e)} type="text"
                                                   placeholder='Enter Last Name'/>
                                            {this.validator.message('last name', lastname, 'required|alpha')}
                                        </Form.Field>
                                        <Form.Field>
                                            <label>Mobile No*</label>
                                            <input name="mobile_no" id="mobile_no" value={mobile_no}
                                                   onBlur={this.mobilecheck.bind(this)} onChange={e => this.change(e)}
                                                   type="text" placeholder='Enter mobile_no'/>
                                            {this.validator.message('mobile no.', mobile_no, 'required|phone|min:10|max:10')}
                                        </Form.Field>
                                        <Form.Field>
                                            <label>Email*</label>
                                            <input name="email" id="email" value={email}
                                                   onBlur={this.emailcheck.bind(this)} onChange={e => this.change(e)}
                                                   type="text" placeholder='Enter Email'/>
                                            {this.validator.message('email', email, 'required|email')}
                                        </Form.Field>
                                        <Form.Field>
                                            <label>Password*</label>
                                            <input name="password" id="password" value={password}
                                                   onChange={e => this.change(e)} type="password"
                                                   placeholder='Enter Password'/>
                                            {this.validator.message('password', password, 'required|min:6')}
                                        </Form.Field>
                                        <Form.Field>
                                            <label>City*</label>
                                            <Dropdown placeholder='Select City' id="city_id" name="city_id" search
                                                      selection options={this.props.city_opt} value={city_id}
                                                      onChange={this.dropDownChange.bind(this)}/>
                                            {this.validator.message('city', city_id, 'required|gt:0')}
                                        </Form.Field>
                                        <Form.Field>
                                            <label>Preference*</label>
                                            <Dropdown placeholder='Select Preference' id="preference_list"
                                                      name="preference_list" search multiple selection
                                                      options={this.props.preference_list_opt} value={preference_list}
                                                      onChange={this.dropDownChange.bind(this)}/>
                                            {this.validator.message('preference', preference_list, 'required|max:3', false, {max: 'Maximum 3 preferences allowed'})}
                                        </Form.Field>
                                        <Form.Field>
                                            <label>How did you find us?*</label>
                                            <Dropdown placeholder='Please Select' id="medium" name="medium" search
                                                      selection options={jsonData.medium} value={medium}
                                                      onChange={this.dropDownChange.bind(this)}/>
                                            {this.validator.message('medium', medium, 'required')}
                                        </Form.Field>
                                        <Form.Field>
                                            <label>What are you looking for?*</label>
                                            <Dropdown placeholder='Please Select' id="is_looking_for"
                                                      name="is_looking_for" search selection
                                                      options={jsonData.looking_for} value={is_looking_for}
                                                      onChange={this.dropDownChange.bind(this)}/>
                                            {this.validator.message('', is_looking_for, 'required|in:' + looking_fors)}
                                        </Form.Field>
                                        <Form.Field>
                                            <label>affiliate Code</label>
                                            <input name="affiliate" value={affiliate} onChange={e => this.change(e)}
                                                   type="text" placeholder='Enter preference_list'/>
                                        </Form.Field>
                                        <Button id="s_reg_submit" className={"btn btn-block btn-lg"}
                                                type='submit'>Submit</Button>
                                    </Form>
                                    <QuestionsFilters/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {/*end of manuel register section*/}
                        <DropDown items={items}/>
                    </div>
                </section>
            )
        }
    }
}

export default RegisterCandidate;
```

my DropDown component code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import DropDownMenu from 'material-ui/DropDownMenu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';

const styles = {
    customWidth: {
        width: 200,
    },
};

class DropDownMenuSimpleExample extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: 1, items: ['abcd', 'efgh']};
    }

    handleChange(event, index, value) {
        return this.setState({value})
    }

    render() {
        let propItems = this.props.items
        return (
            <DropDownMenu
                value={this.state.value}
                onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                style={styles.customWidth}
                autoWidth={false}
            >
                {(propItems !== null || propItems != 'undefined' ) ? (propItems).map((item, index) => <MenuItem key={index} value={1}
                                                                                   primaryText="Custom height"/>) : (this.state.items).map((item, index) =>
                    <MenuItem key={index} value={1} primaryText="Custom width"/>)}
            </DropDownMenu>
        );
    }
}

export default DropDownMenuSimpleExample
```

it is telling me that It cannot call map on null and in the first render the value of props shows undefined but then it is defined so not able to get to render the DropDown element properly..

any help will be highly appreciated

Please Note :- with just the state I get the proper dropdown but the issue happens only when I am passing props as data for the dropdown

Comment: How are you using `DropdownMenuSimpleExample` exactly? Also, your condition is passing when `propItems === undefined`. Change `||` for `&&` and try to stick to strict comparisons only (`!== ` instead of `!=`)

Comment: I am exporting this DropdownMenuSimpleExample component and then in my container I am importing this as the DropDown component to which I am passing the data as props to populate my dropdown

Comment: Can you share the container code? or at least its render method? If you're passing the items directly hardcoded as you show at the top there is no way that they're undefined

Comment: I have added the full container code , please check and advise